# Parallel program no speed increase vs linear program

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, pipeline

I have created a model program of a more complex program that will utilize multithreading and multiple harddrives to increase performance. The data size is so large that reading all data into memory will not be feasible so the data will be read, processed, and written back out in chunks. This test program uses pipeline design to be able to read, process and write out at the same time on 3 different threads. Because read and write are to different harddrive, there is no problem with read and write at the same time. However, the program utilizing multithread seems to run 2x slower than its linear version(also in the code). I have tried to have the read and write thread not be destoryed after running a chunk but the synchronization seem to have slowed it down even more than the current version. I was wondering if I am doing something wrong or how I can improve this. Thank You.

Tested using i3-2100 @ 3.1ghz and 16GB ram.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>
#include <thread>

#define CHUNKSIZE 8192    //size of each chunk to process
#define DATASIZE 2097152  //total size of data

using namespace std;

int data[3][CHUNKSIZE];
int run = 0;
int totalRun = DATASIZE/CHUNKSIZE;

bool finishRead = false, finishWrite = false;

ifstream infile;
ofstream outfile;

clock_t starttime, endtime;

/*
    Process a chunk of data(simulate only, does not require to sort all data)
*/
void quickSort(int arr[], int left, int right) {

    int i = left, j = right;
    int tmp;
    int pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2];

    while (i <= j) {
        while (arr[i] < pivot) i++;
        while (arr[j] > pivot) j--;
        if (i <= j) {
            tmp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = tmp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    };

    if (left < j) quickSort(arr, left, j);
    if (i < right) quickSort(arr, i, right);
}

/*
    Find runtime
*/
void diffclock(){
    double diff = (endtime - starttime)/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    cout<<"Total run time: "<<diff<<"ms"<<endl;
}

/*
    Read a chunk of data
*/
void readData(){

    for(int i = 0; i < CHUNKSIZE; i++){
        infile>>data[run%3][i];
    }
    finishRead = true;

}

/*
    Write a chunk of data
*/
void writeData(){

    for(int i = 0; i < CHUNKSIZE; i++){
        outfile<<data[(run-2)%3][i]<<endl;
    }
    finishWrite = true;
}

/*
    Pipelines Read, Process, Write using multithread
*/
void threadtransfer(){

    starttime = clock();

    infile.open("/home/pcg/test/iothread/source.txt");
    outfile.open("/media/pcg/Data/test/iothread/ThreadDuplicate.txt");

    thread read, write;

    run = 0;
    readData();

    run = 1;
    readData();
    quickSort(data[(run-1)%3], 0, CHUNKSIZE - 1);

    run = 2;
    while(run < totalRun){
        //cout<<run<<endl;
        finishRead = finishWrite = false;
        read = thread(readData);
        write = thread(writeData);
        read.detach();
        write.detach();
        quickSort(data[(run-1)%3], 0, CHUNKSIZE - 1);
        while(!finishRead||!finishWrite){}  //check if next cycle is ready.
        run++;
    }


    quickSort(data[(run-1)%3], 0, CHUNKSIZE - 1);
    writeData();

    run++;
    writeData();

    infile.close();
    outfile.close();

    endtime = clock();
    diffclock();
}

/*
    Linearly read, sort, and write a chunk and repeat.
*/
void lineartransfer(){

    int totalRun = DATASIZE/CHUNKSIZE;
    int holder[CHUNKSIZE];
    starttime = clock();

    infile.open("/home/pcg/test/iothread/source.txt");
    outfile.open("/media/pcg/Data/test/iothread/Linearduplicate.txt");

    run = 0;

    while(run < totalRun){

        for(int i = 0; i < CHUNKSIZE; i++) infile>>holder[i];
        quickSort(holder, 0, CHUNKSIZE - 1);
        for(int i = 0; i < CHUNKSIZE; i++) outfile<<holder[i]<<endl;
        run++;
    }

    endtime = clock();
    diffclock();
}

/*
    Create large amount of data for testing
*/
void createData(){
    outfile.open("/home/pcg/test/iothread/source.txt");

    for(int i = 0; i < DATASIZE; i++){
        outfile<<rand()<<endl;

    }
    outfile.close();
}



int main(){

    int mode=0;
    cout<<"Number of threads: "<<thread::hardware_concurrency()<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter mode\n1.Create Data\n2.thread copy\n3.linear copy\ninput mode:";
    cin>>mode;

    if(mode == 1) createData();
    else if(mode == 2) threadtransfer();
    else if(mode == 3) lineartransfer();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are measuing time using `clock` on a Linux machine, I expect that the total CPU time is (roughly) the same whether you run one thread or multiple threads.

Maybe you want to use `time myprog` instead? Or use `gettimeofday` to fetch the time (which will give you a time in seconds + nanoseconds [although the nanoseconds may not be "accurate" down to the last digit].

Edit: 
Next, don't use `endl` when writing to a file. It slows things down a lot, because the C++ runtime goes and flushes to the file, which is an operating system call. It is almost certainly somehow protected against multiple threads, so you have three threads doing write-data, a single line, synchronously, at a time. Most likely going to take nearly 3x as long as running a single thread. Also, don't write to the same file from three different threads - that's going to be bad in one way or another.

Comment: howver overall, the runtime is still much slower than the linear version.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the advise. The clock does seem to be the problem. Without looking at the time output, both does seem to run at similar time.

Comment: Your file handling is definitely also a problem, I guarantee it!

Answer (score 2):

Don't busy-wait. This wastes precious CPU time and may well slow down the rest (not to mention the compiler can optimize it into an infinite loop because it can't guess whether those flags will change or not, so it's not even correct in the first place). And don't `detach()` either. Replace both `detach()` and busy-waiting with `join()`:

```
while (run < totalRun) {
    read = thread(readData);
    write = thread(writeData);
    quickSort(data[(run-1)%3], 0, CHUNKSIZE - 1);
    read.join();
    write.join();
    run++;
}
```

---

As to the global design, well, ignoring the global variables I guess it's otherwise acceptable if you don't expect the processing (`quickSort`) part to ever exceed the read/write time. I for one would use message queues to pass the buffers between the various threads (which allows to add more processing threads if you need it, either doing the same tasks in parallel or different tasks in sequence) but maybe that's because I'm used to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I am wrong, but it seems your threaded function is basically a linear function doing 3 times the work of your linear function?

In a threaded program you would create three threads and run the readData/quicksort functions once on each thread (distributing thee workload), but in your program it seems like the thread simulation is actually just reading three times, quicksorting three times, and writing three times, and totalling the time it takes to do all three of each.

Comment: In threadtransfer function, the function call outside the While loop is used to setup/finish the pipeline as you need to first read data into memory before you can process it the next cycle. Only inside the while loop part would all 3 process run at the same time.